# Exporting feature collection after being flattened using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to export a feature collection of feature collections after being flattened. I cannot get the collection exported with the columns appended (in return value) and just flag an error with 'reduceRegion'.

Can anyone help me export this collection?

The link is here for what I'm trying to do: https://code.earthengine.google.com/c1b2986ccd3019b8bd94220d887a0c32